# MS Access Me.Refresh doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm using an MS Access 2010 databse (.accdb) to connect to a database in SQL Server 2016.

I have a form, which uses a linked table to a SQL Server view as it's record source, which enables users to browse a set of records. The form has a button which opens as separate form, in dialog mode, to enable a user to edit a selected record from the browse form.  Here's the code of the button;

```
Private Sub btnEdit_Click()
Dim RecordNumber As Integer

On Error GoTo btnEdit_Click_Err

'open the data entry form in edit mode, showing the currently selected record from the browse form
DoCmd.OpenForm "Application Edit - Template", acNormal, "", "[DB_Key]=" & txtDBKey, acEdit, acDialog
Me.Refresh

btnEdit_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

btnEdit_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume btnEdit_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

The Me.Refresh method call is not refreshing the form with the changes made on the edit form.

I know that if I use Me.Requery I can force a refresh of the data but unfortunately this also navigates focus to the first record in the data set.  I know that I can save the record number to a variable and then use DoCmd.GoToRecord to navigate back.  I just would rather MS Access work the way it's supposed to.

Does anyone know why Me.Refresh doesn't work?